# How to start a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using some code from the iReporter tutorial app from http://www.raywenderlich.com/.

I got this code in the StreamScreen.m:

```
-(void)refreshStream {
    //just call the "stream" command from the web API
    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"stream", @"command", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        //got stream
        [self showStream:[json objectForKey:@"result"]];
    }];
}
```

How can I put the result from the json into a tableview. I want to use the tableview instead of the scrollview.

Comment: @user2908800 Given that your question is actually about [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you should more carefully title and tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your `json` data in array. using `objectForKey` and then bind that data into tablview using below tablview methods

and Declare the tablview delegate and dataSource in .h like this

.h File

```
  <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

.m File put this code

```
  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {

            return 1;

      }

     -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {

            return [stream count];


      }

      -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {


            AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            }
            cell.textLabel.text=[stream objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;


}
```

Try this code....